# Convert Azure Blob object to MP3

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I'm actually retrieving audio files from Azure Blob Storage and I'd like to convert them back to the original format (mp3 format).

I'm retrieving the audio using `Pyspark` in `Databricks` as shown in the following code:

```py
input_audio = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("test.mp3")
```

the `input_audio` is a PySpark Dataframe, I'd like to convert it to mp3.

How can I achieve it ? Thanks!

I've tried to write the content (Binary data) into a new `.mp3` file but it didn't work.

Comment: why not just read file as binary using the "normal" file API?

Comment: Actually I'm reading it without a problem but as a Binary file and I want to convert it to mp3, do you have any suggestions to convert it back to mp3 ? Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to do file actions (copying, moving etc.) with the mp3 or actually do some sort of pyspark transformations on the mp3 data?

Comment: @restlessmodem Actually I'd like to convert it into .wav so I'd like to restore it as mp3 then convert it to .wav. So, it's not really Pyspark

Comment: @manou.MHD pyspark is not really the right tool for this, with pyspark you can work great with structured data like CSVs. Maybe look for a library that is specialized on audio file conversion

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem :

First I've used Pyspark to get the content of the audio file

```
input_audio = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("test.mp3")
# extracting audio binary content (there's several methods to extract column value)
binary_data = input_audio.collect()[0][3]
```

Then I've just written the binary data into a new mp3 file, as shown here:

```
with open('new.mp3', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(binary_data)
```

Thank you everyone !